# Disk quota after file removal

Tags: linux, quota

I have an account on some free ssh accessed linux server. The disk per user quota is 100MB. Recently I've downloaded a file abot 80MB and next tried to unzip it. And then an error occured saying the disk quota is being exceeded (I forgot about the quota limitation before the whole operation). Now I've deleted the compressed 80MB leaving in my home dir several really small files but even after the big file removal when i check my quota it says about 90MB even if, as i've said i removed the big archive file. What can i do to "reset" the quota? I really need the disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Review the space your files are using. Any number of tools to do this. For an interactive view of utilization try:

```
ncdu ~
```

100 MB cannot uncompress a 80 MB file. Likely the uncompressed copy alone is larger than 100 MB. Plus, you need the compressed copy until it is extracted.

You value more space. Pay to rent an instance with larger disks from your favorite provider.